# Showing that the map that takes $u_0$ to solution $u(t)$ is self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Let $u$ and $v$ be the solution of the heat equation
$$w'(t) - \Delta w(t) =0$$
with initial data $u_0$ and $v_0$ respectively, and with either homogeneous Dirichlet or Neumann BCs on a bounded domain $\Omega$.

Define $S(t):L^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ by $S(t)u_0 = u(t)$ be the mapping taking initial data to the solution evaluated at time $t$.

How can I show that $S(t)$ is self-adjoint **without using Green's kernel**? It amounts to showing that
$$(u(t), v_0)_{L^2} = (v(t), u_0)_{L^2}$$
but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0 \le s \le t$, the selfadjointness of $\Delta$ gives
\begin{align}
          \frac{\partial}{\partial s}(u(t-s),v(s))
           & =-(u'(t-s),v(s))+(u(t-s),v'(s)) \\
           & =-(\Delta u(t-s),v(s))+(u(t-s),\Delta v(s)) =0.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
             (u(t-s),v(s)|_{s=0} = (u(t-s),v(s))|_{s=t} \\
             (u(t),v_0)  =(u_0,v(t)).
$$